# Pushing an entire directory from local computer to github.com

Tags: git, version-control, directory

I have a directory named "FilmReview" in my computer and `FilmReview.git` in my github and it is empty I want to push this folder into `https://github.com/siddhartha-ramesh/FilmReview.git`.

I tried the following:

```
siddhartha@siddhartha-Inspiron-545s ~/Desktop/Untitled Folder $ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/siddhartha/Desktop/Untitled Folder/.git/
siddhartha@siddhartha-Inspiron-545s ~/Desktop/Untitled Folder $ git add .
siddhartha@siddhartha-Inspiron-545s ~/Desktop/Untitled Folder $ git commit -m "The whole Project"
[master (root-commit) 02a49f5] The whole Project
 203 files changed, 39049 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 film_review/.project
 create mode 100644 film_review/404.html
#Rest of the files in this folder
 create mode 100644 film_review/trailers.html
 create mode 100644 film_review/trailers.html~

siddhartha@siddhartha-Inspiron-545s ~/.ssh $ ls -a
.  ..  key  key.pub  known_hosts
siddhartha@siddhartha-Inspiron-545s ~/.ssh $ cat key.pub
ssh-rsa 
# KEY HERE 

siddhartha@siddhartha-Inspiron-545s ~/Desktop/Untitled Folder $ git remote add origin git@github.com:siddhartha-ramesh/FilmReview.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.
siddhartha@siddhartha-Inspiron-545s ~/Desktop/Untitled Folder $ git push origin master
To git@github.com:siddhartha-ramesh/FilmReview.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:siddhartha-ramesh/FilmReview.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Someone please help me out

And also I did this, but no file is uploaded to my git hub

```
siddhartha@siddhartha-Inspiron-545s ~/Desktop/Untitled Folder $ git push origin master
Username for 'https://github.com': siddhartha-ramesh
Password for 'https://siddhartha-ramesh@github.com': 
To https://github.com/siddhartha-ramesh/FilmReview.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/siddhartha-ramesh/FilmReview.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
siddhartha@siddhartha-Inspiron-545s ~/Desktop/Untitled Folder $ git pill origin master
git: 'pill' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean this?
    pull
siddhartha@siddhartha-Inspiron-545s ~/Desktop/Untitled Folder $ git pull origin master
warning: no common commits
remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
From https://github.com/siddhartha-ramesh/FilmReview
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 README.md | 4 ++++
 1 file changed, 4 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 README.md
```

Comment: As it says, try `git pull` than push to origin master again..

Comment: Type `git pull` and press enter to fetch changes from the remote branch, than `git push origin master` again to add your files.. If thats not working you maybe better `git clone git@github.com:siddhartha-ramesh/FilmReview.git` into a new directory, than add the files, and than `git push`..

Comment: I always get this message:
git remote add origin git@github.com:
siddhartha@siddhartha-Inspiron-545s ~/Desktop/Untitled Folder $ git push origin master
To git@github.com:siddhartha-ramesh/FilmReview.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:siddhartha-ramesh/FilmReview.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: Than clone your project in a new directory using `git clone git@github.com:siddhartha-ramesh/FilmReview.git`. Add the files from the directory you working in now. And than `git push` to add these files.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31058/discussion-between-tim-and-swaroop-nagendra)

Answer (score 1):

The message `warning: no common commits` means that there is already a commit in the github repo. Since you have created your own repo locally too, the two repos do not have a common ancestor. That is why you cannot push.

When you created the github repository you probably checked the option *Initialize this repository with a README*

[image]

I would advise you to remove the current repo on github and create a new one without an inital commit, i.e. do not check the checkbox above. Then you can start by pushing your repo to  the remote.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you figured out because your repo on GitHub is not empty anymore.

Anyway, I think what you were looking for is this:

```
git push origin master -f
```

Without `-f` (force) your push didn't work because the repo on GitHub and your local repo had no common history. (Most probably because you initialized the GitHub repo with a `README`)

The `-f` forces the push, even if the remote branch has no common ancestor with the local one, or the two branches have diverged. But as you said the GitHub repo was supposed to be empty anyway, so this is safe to do.